# What's the difference between the two java codes? (Generic class)

Tags: java, function, generics

```
private <E> Optional<E> safe(@NotNull List<E> l, Integer o) { return l.size() > o ? Optional.of(l.get(o)) : Optional.empty(); }
```

```
public <E> void test() {
    Function<List<E>, Function<Integer, Optional<E>>> safe = l -> i -> l.size() > i ? Optional.of(l.get(i)) : Optional.empty();
    List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<>();

    Optional<SomeClass> element1 = safe(list, 0);
    Optional<SomeClass> element2 = safe.apply(list).apply(0); // doesn't work this line;
}
```

Generic class E of "Function<List<E>, Function<Integer, Optional<E>>> safe" can't cognize SomeClass to E

What's the difference between the two codes?

class casting dose work. but i want to know difference between the two

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, I will call the 2-parameter method "`safeMethod`", and call the local variable of type `Function<List<E>, Function<Integer, Optional<E>>>` "`safeLocal`".

The difference is that `safeMethod` is generic and `safeLocal.apply` is not (but `test` *is*).

`safeMethod` is generic - it can take a `List<E>` for *any* reference type `E`. In the call `safeMethod(list, 0);`, `E` is inferred to be `SomeClass`. It can be said that the type argument for the type parameter `E` in this call is `SomeClass`.

On the other hand, the `apply` method of `safeLocal` takes *one specific type* - `List<E>`. [`apply`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html#apply(T)) is not generic after all. Note that this `E` type refers to *one specific type* - the type argument passed to `test`. Is `SomeClass` that type argument? Not necessarily. Since `test` is generic, `E` can be *any* reference type, not necessarily `SomeClass`. Therefore, you cannot pass `List<SomeClass>` to `safeLocal.apply`.

For a concrete example, let's say you are calling `test` from another method in the same class,

```
public void anotherMethodInTheSameClassAsTest() {
    // you could do:
    this.<SomeClass>test(); // 1
    // but since test is generic and E can be any reference type,
    // you could also do
    this.<String>test(); // 2
}
```

For `// 1`, the type argument for the type parameter `E` for `test` would be `SomeClass`. For `// 2` however, it would be `String`! `safeLocal.apply` is supposed to take a `List<String>` in this case, not a `List<SomeClass>`.

Though in practice, generics don't exist at runtime, and all `safeLocal` is really doing is returning an empty optional. `test` isn't even doing anything to that. So the type doesn't really matter in this particular case, which is why casting can "fix" this.

If you want to make a generic local variable that can be `apply`'ed with different kinds of lists, you need to declare your own interface that actually has a generic `apply` in it, and *not* use a lambda. Lambdas unfortunately can't be generic :(

```
interface SafeListAccessFunction {
    <E> Optional<E> apply(@NotNull List<E> l, Integer o);
}
```

```
SafeListAccessFunction safe = new SafeListAccessFunction() {
    @Override
    public <E> Optional<E> apply(@NotNull List<E> l, Integer o) {
        return l.size() > o ? Optional.of(l.get(o)) : Optional.empty();
    }
};
```

Or if you want it curried:

```
interface SafeListAccessFunction {
    <E> Function<Integer, Optional<E>> apply(@NotNull List<E> l);
}
```

```
SafeListAccessFunction safe = new SafeListAccessFunction() {
    @Override
    public <E> Function<Integer, Optional<E>> apply(@NotNull List<E> l) {
        return o -> l.size() > o ? Optional.of(l.get(o)) : Optional.empty();
    }
};
```